# Streamreader.readLine reads lines through one

Tags: c#

I need to read text from txt-file in array. I do it like this

```
string[] rows = new string[1500000];
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(adress);
        int count = 0;
        while (file.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            rows[count] = file.ReadLine();
            count++;
        }
        file.Close();
```

But in target array are only a half of lines.[It is the result of working this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsTFw.png). [And this is source file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDw37.png). StreamReader read file through one line/ so I lost a half of data. How can i avoid this?

Comment: Why don't you use `File.ReadAllLines()` ?

Comment: Add your images in question  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83096/how-to-place-an-image-in-a-stack-overflow-question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even-numbered rows appear skipped because each iteration of the loop calls `ReadLine` twice:

- The first call is in the header of the loop
- The second call is in the body, on the assignment line

You can fix this by assigning the result of the call to a variable inside the header:

```
string lastLine;
while ((lastLine = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    rows[count] = lastLine;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  **File.ReadAllLines** Which reads all text to array

```
string[] rows = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```